# iOS Swift Page View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Hi guys I got 4 errors at;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource{ // error1: Expected ',' separator
```

here is the first error with the error message: Expected ',' separator

```
//For Navigation Bar Tint and BG Color
var NavBarBGColor = CommonUtilities.RGBColor("#2574A9")
var NavBarTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles: NSArray!
var pageImages: NSArray!

@IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  //Navigation Bar Tint and BG Color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = NavBarTintColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = NavBarBGColor

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Menu Button Click
    Open.target = self.revealViewController()
    Open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

    //Pan Gesture Recognizer for page navigation
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        //Page View Controller for Men
        self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "Try","And")
        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "dummying - men","dummying - women")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self //error2: Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource?'
```

here is the second error with the error message: Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource?'

```
    var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentMenuViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: Forward animated: true, completion: nil) //error2: Use of unresolved identifier 'Forward'
```

here is the second error with the error message: Use of unresolved identifier 'Forward'

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}

@IBAction func MenuRestartBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentMenuViewController
{
if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0)) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)
{
    return ContentMenuViewController()
}

var vc: ContentMenuViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("") as! ContentMenuViewController


vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
vc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index] as! String
vc.pageIndex = index

return vc
}

 //Page View Controller Data Source
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) ->UIViewController?
{
    var vc = viewController as! ContentMenuViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil
    }

    index--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func pageViewController(pageController: UIPageViewController, ViewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{

var vc = viewController as! ContentMenuViewController
var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

if (index == NSNotFound){
    return nil
}

index ++

    if (index == self.pageTitles.count)//error3: Expected expression after operator
```

here is the second error with the error message: Expected expression after operator
        {
        return nil
        }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return self.pageTitles.count
}
func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

}
```

thanks for the help guys..

Comment: 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'viewControllerAtIndex'

Comment: I edited my answer as well @RH34Serenity

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Well, the second error is because of the first one. The first error makes no sense at all, I would recommend you to `Product -> Clean`.

And the other 2 errors, try writing it this way `.Forward` (That Forward has to be inside an enum, I hope there's somewhere in your code you haven't posted).

Comment: 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'viewControllerAtIndex'

Comment: I solved your problem, if you have any other, write it here or edit your question

Comment: I think you should pay more attention to the tutorial, I suggest you doing it again

Comment: still error in those lines and addtional error to the code you gave

Comment: The problem is you have no idea what you are doing, watch some Swift tutorials first

Comment: hi done editing my codes please check for the latest updates thanks